# Properly escaping asterisk/glob in (z)sh script

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, wildcards, escape-characters

I have the following Problem, I need an environment variable that contains globbing characters as clear text, and I can't seem to escape them. Escaping with backslash works, but for some reason the backslash is still part of the string."

Disabling GLOB_SUBST resolves the problem, but I´d like to avoid that.

I used the following to narrow down the problem:

```bsh
touch foo; chmod +x ./foo

# glob expansion i.E. $test contains all files in the directory.
echo 'export test="*"; echo $test' > foo; source ./foo 

# no glob expansion, but the escape character is added to the string.
echo 'export test="\*"; echo $test' > foo; source ./foo  
# output: \*
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Simply quote the `test` variable `"$test"`?

Comment: .. or use `noglob echo $test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you assign the string `*` to the variable, and since `globsubst` is enabled, the unquoted expansion `$test` is subject to globbing (as in a POSIX shell). In the second case, you assign the string `\*`, but it's not expanded as a glob since the backslash escapes the asterisk. (Otherwise zsh would complain that there were no matching files found, unless you've disabled that, too. You probably don't have filenames starting with a backslash anyway, but the glob to match them would have to be `\\*`.)

To stop the globbing, quote the variable expansion, i.e. `echo "$test"`.

See: [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)

Also, you don't need `export` if you're just going to use the variables within the same shell (even between the main shell and the sourced script).